# Python script to download fromShareSync (Cloud file storage)

Tags: python

We've got this script working with GoogleDrive but having trouble making it work with Sharesync. Probably because the link when opened in Browser is executing some embedded JS to initiate the download. Anyone able to help with a clever way to make it work?

The ShareSync link in question is: https://sharesync.serverdata.net/uk/s/file?public_share=rkUqx5GwcUafPMHtcgTSMX00000464

```py
import os
DownTo = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
fileName='MouseJiggle.exe'
fromURL='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

import ctypes
print DownTo

class disable_file_system_redirection:
    _disable = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection
    _revert = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_value = ctypes.c_long()
        self.success = self._disable(ctypes.byref(self.old_value))
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.success:
            self._revert(self.old_value)

import subprocess        
with disable_file_system_redirection(): 
        import urllib
import os

def downloadFile(DownTo, fromURL, fileName):
    try:
        DownTo = os.path.join(DownTo, fileName)
        print "DownTo",DownTo
        print "fileName",fileName
        with open(DownTo, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(urllib.urlopen(fromURL).read())
        if os.path.isfile(DownTo):
            return '{} - {}KB'.format(DownTo, os.path.getsize(DownTo)/1000)
    except:
        return 'Please Check URL or Download Path!'

if __name__=='__main__':
    print downloadFile(DownTo, fromURL, fileName)
```

Comment: Hello again! Do you have a link for testing purposes whose contents are a bit easier to check on macOS? A text file might be enough, ideally it would be good to test multiple types of content. Speaking of, will you be downloading only a particular type?

Comment: Yup. I've updated the link so it points to a TXT file. Generally we'll be downloading installer files and the like (exe, msi, etc) but I imagine if it'll work for one format, we shouldn't have too much issues with others.

Comment: Great! I'm making progress, right now I'm trying to find the best way to check that the download is complete, and how to obtain the file name from the page.